# C: getting an "@" sign in printf when I wrote "b"

Tags: c

In C, I do:

```
char* buffer=p->content;       // p is a struct type and content is a char*
printf("buffer:%s\n",buffer);
```

My output is this:

```
@uffer: �@��^��0z
```

I don't quite know why I get �@��^��0z, but I suspect is has to do with me incrementing mypointer incorrectly.

My main question is: Why is my "b" being converted to an "@" sign????????

Comment: Print random garbage, get random garbage. You've probably got a carriage return `'\r'` in that garbage buffer somewhere, followed by `@`.

Comment: I don't think so because the previous print statements come out clear and print what I expected them to...

Comment: Your comment isn't relevant to what nneonneo explained to you. If you're on linux, pipe your output into od -c and you'll see the '\r' (ctrl-m). Or redirect your output to a file and then examine it with a hex editor.

Comment: 'p is a struct type and content is a char*' ... that points to what?

Comment: No, he implied no such thing. Try reading it again, this time for comprehension. You're a rookie who wants help; try listening instead of arguing.

Comment: The fact that a previous print worked correctly only means that your data was not corrupted / your pointer was valid at that time. You can easily prove this by following the suggestion @Jim gave -- pipe the output into a tool that lets you actually see all your data (the console does not). Alternatively, use a debugger and examine memory prior to the print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage data you are printing coincidentally contains a line printer control character known as carriage return, which your display device is interpreting as a command to move the cursor to the beginning of the line. Then if a @ character occurs, it overwrites the first character of your output.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the mempory `buffer` is pointing to is not initialised, and so you are getting random data.

You really need to show us where `p->content` comes from (is set).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: aha! I printed p content and got garbage...I will go fix it

Comment: It looks like an answer to me. It could be expanded to explain how the @ overwrote the b on the screen, but that's not really what the OP cares about.